# DHT11 analog or digital?

Tags: analogread, temperature-sensor, digital, analog, dht22

I saw some projects with DHT11, some connect it with analog pin, others connect with digital pin.

Is there any difference / advantage connecting to the analog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DHT11 is a digital component with its own digital communication protocol.

Analog pins can be used for either analog input *or* digital input and output.

You can use a digital device like the DHT11 on *any* pin, whether it is labelled analog or digital (except on a couple of boards which have a few analog-only pins).